# HTTParty POST is sending a GET

Tags: ruby, github-api, httparty

I'm hitting Github's v3 rest [api](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment), I'm making a POST request attempting to create a comment on a test PR. I'm getting back a 200 response, and upon inspecting the request, it was sent as a GET, not a POST:

```
response = HTTParty.post(
    "http://api.github.com/repos/my_github/my_repo/issues/1/comments",
    body: { body: "works" }.to_json,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer #{ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN']}",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "User-Agent": ENV["GITHUB_USER_AGENT"]
    }
)

response.request
=> #<HTTParty::Request:0x007fdd45a42688
 @http_method=Net::HTTP::Get,
 @last_response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>,
 @last_uri=#<URI::HTTPS https://api.github.com/repos/my_github/my_repo/issues/1/comments>,
 @options=
  {:limit=>4,
   :assume_utf16_is_big_endian=>true,
   :default_params=>{},
   :follow_redirects=>true,
   :parser=>HTTParty::Parser,
   :uri_adapter=>URI,
   :connection_adapter=>HTTParty::ConnectionAdapter,
   :body=>{:body=>"works"},
   :headers=>
    {:Authorization=>"Bearer my_token",
     :Accept=>"application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json",
     :"Content-Type"=>"application/json",
     :"User-Agent"=>"me"}},
 @path=#<URI::HTTPS https://api.github.com/repos/my_github/my_repo/issues/1/comments>,
```

The response body is a list of all the comments on that PR, which is the GET request to that same url. I have no idea why it's not sending a POST. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your request to use HTTPS, not HTTP:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/my_github/my_repo/issues/1/comments
```

instead of:

```
http://api.github.com/repos/my_github/my_repo/issues/1/comments
```

and you get:

```
response.request
=> #<HTTParty::Request:0x00007ffdb81c7e48 @changed_hosts=false, @credentials_sent=false, @http_method=Net::HTTP::Post ...
```

as well as:

```
response.code
=> 201
```

Comment: This does not answer the question in why it would perform a get when a post request was queried instead. Whats the relation between using https and the wrong method being used?

Comment: Because of redirection

Comment: Ouch. Thanks for the explanation!